# A cyclomatic complexity Scala syntax error with a match-case situation

Tags: scala

Working on a cyclomatic complexity Scala syntax error, I am running out of idea on the last error.

It is a data file parsing situation. The following is the code segment:

```
val lineString = line.mkString(",")
line match {
  case Seq("Data1Name", data1ID, "desc1", "..") if data1ID.matches("\\d+") => {
    processData1(...)
  }
  case Seq("Data2Name", data2ID, "desc2", "..") if data2ID.matches("\\d+")  => {
    processData2(...)
  }
  case Seq("Data3Name", data3ID, "desc3", "...") if data3ID.matches("\\d+")  => {
    processData3(...)
  }
  case Seq("Data4Name", data4ID, "desc4", "...") if data4ID.matches("\\d+")  => {
    processData4(...)
  }
  case Seq("Data5Name", data5ID, "desc5", "...", data5xID, '...', ...) if data5ID.matches("\\d+") && data5xID.matches("\\d+") => { // <-- It would be fine if this block is commented out
    processData5(...)
  }
  case _ => Some(Error(s"..."))
}
```

The cyclomatic complexity is 13. The syntax check will be happy if I comment out the block indicated above. I can't see how I can simplify the code any further.

BTW, the complexity is reduced by 1 if I replace the two conductions inside the if statement with a method on the block 5. To me, the approach increases the complexity.

Any suggestions?

Also, the syntax error,

```
Cyclomatic complexity of 13 exceeds max of 10
```

is generated by the Scala Style Check installed in our build process.

Comment: maybe if we could have a look at the `seq` content and `if` conditions we could suggest some simplification (if any).

Comment: Thanks. I will do so.

Comment: What's the error? It's produced by whom exactly?

Comment: static code analysis, I guess.

Comment: The error is highlighted for the whole method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that your code is bad, except that it can be simplified a bit:

```
val decimal = "(\\d+)".r

line match {
  case Seq("Data1Name", decimal(_), "desc1", "..")  =>
    processData1(...)
  case Seq("Data2Name", decimal(_), "desc2", "..")  =>
    processData2(...)
  case Seq("Data3Name", decimal(_), "desc3", "...") =>
    processData3(...)
  case Seq("Data4Name", decimal(_), "desc4", "...") => 
    processData4(...)
  case Seq("Data5Name", decimal(_), "desc5", "...", decimal(_), '...', ...) => 
    processData5(...)
  case _ => Some(Error(s"..."))
}
```

Justification for [CyclomaticComplexityChecker](http://www.scalastyle.org/rules-dev.html#org_scalastyle_scalariform_CyclomaticComplexityChecker) says:

> If the code is too complex, then this can make code hard to read.

Your code is not complex and it's not hard to read, so I think it's ok to [silence checker](http://www.scalastyle.org/configuration.html) for this particular case.

**But!** If your code snippet is just the part of the longer method, then checker is right and you need to simplify your method. Do it by extracting this part into separate method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code segment is the full method body. Anything is left out.

Comment: Using the regular expression in the fashion does reduce the complexity. Thanks again.

Comment: Beautiful simplification.